# CMake find ImageMagick doesn't work on Windows

Tags: windows, cmake, imagemagick

```
find_package( ImageMagick 6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Magick++ MagickCore )
```

works on Linux, but on Windows I got an error:

```
Could NOT find ImageMagick (missing: ImageMagick_Magick++_LIBRARY
ImageMagick_MagickCore_LIBRARY) (found suitable version "6.9.10-80",
minimum required is "6")
```

I have properly installed ImageMagick with all libs and headers. Everything is in the INCLUDE and LIB, PATH pathes.

CMake found ImageMagick, but can't find components. How can I fix it?

ImageMagick libraries locates in `c:\3rdparty\lib` where I have `CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib` and `CORE_RL_magick_.lib`.

CMake version is 3.16.2

Comment: The script `FindImageMagick.cmake` contains the code devoted for find a library file corresponded to `Magick++` component. Hardcoded list of possible names for such library is [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindImageMagick.cmake#L202). Do you have a library file with one of the given names? If yes, then show its absolute path.

Comment: I have `c:\3rdparty\bin\CORE_RL_magick_.dll` and `c:\3rdparty\bin\CORE_RL_Magick++_.dll`. And corresponded `*.lib` files in `c:\3rdparty\lib`

Comment: Ok, the path `c:\3rdparty\lib\CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib` should fit to that search. For completeness, which CMake version do you use on Windows? (BTW, you may incorporate this information and the information from your previous comment into the question post).

Answer (score 2):

Problem was in that `c:\3rdparty\lib` is a directory added to `LIB` system environment variable, that was missed by CMake search with `find_library()` as there is disabled search in specific environments variables.

I edited `FindImageMagick.cmake` and commented this restriction:

```
function(FIND_IMAGEMAGICK_API component header)
  set(ImageMagick_${component}_FOUND FALSE PARENT_SCOPE)

  pkg_check_modules(PC_${component} QUIET ${component})

  find_path(ImageMagick_${component}_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES ${header}
    HINTS
      ${PC_${component}_INCLUDEDIR}
      ${PC_${component}_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    PATHS
      ${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS}
      "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\ImageMagick\\Current;BinPath]/include"
    PATH_SUFFIXES
      ImageMagick ImageMagick-6 ImageMagick-7
    DOC "Path to the ImageMagick arch-independent include dir."
#    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    )
  find_path(ImageMagick_${component}_ARCH_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES magick/magick-baseconfig.h
    HINTS
      ${PC_${component}_INCLUDEDIR}
      ${PC_${component}_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    PATHS
      ${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS}
      "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\ImageMagick\\Current;BinPath]/include"
    PATH_SUFFIXES
      ImageMagick ImageMagick-6 ImageMagick-7
    DOC "Path to the ImageMagick arch-specific include dir."
#    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    )
  find_library(ImageMagick_${component}_LIBRARY
    NAMES ${ARGN}
    HINTS
      ${PC_${component}_LIBDIR}
      ${PC_${component}_LIB_DIRS}
    PATHS
      "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\ImageMagick\\Current;BinPath]/lib"
    DOC "Path to the ImageMagick Magick++ library."
#    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    )
```

And voila, now CMake able to find my ImageMagick.